# Setting function's prototype to a private variable

Tags: javascript, scope, prototype

I am essentially trying to set a function's prototype within the function itself. The purpose is to hide many functions inside one public function, yet keep the functionality.

Here is the non-working code in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j6zd9/). The intended behaviour is displaying "Greetings!" and "Take me to your leader."

The code can be 'fixed' by moving the `Outer.prototype` lines and the `Extensions` function out of the `Outer` function to the global scope. However, this means the `Extensions` function is public and free for direct use, which it shouldn't be.

What would be a good way to achieve this 'private' behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not work because you are **overriding** the prototype. When you call `new Outer`, then `this` will inherit from the *current* `Outer.prototype`. You are then overriding `Object.prototype` inside the function, but it does not affect the currently created instance, only future ones.
You'd have to *extend* the existing prototype.

But if you want hide certain functions, use a **self-invoking function**:

```
var Outer = (function() {

    function Extensions() {
    }
    Extensions.protoype.Greet = function () {
        alert(this.Greetings);
    }

    function Inner() {
        Extensions.call(this);
        this.Greetings = "Take me to your leader.";
    }
    Inner.prototype = Object.create(Extensions.prototype);
    Inner.prototype.constructor = Inner;

    function Outer() {
        Extensions.call(this);
        this.Greetings = "Greetings!";
    }
    Outer.prototype = Object.create(Extensions.prototype);
    Outer.prototype.constructor = Outer;

    Outer.prototype.getInner = function() {
        return new Inner();
    };

    return Outer;

}());
```

Here, `Extensions` is defined inside the immediately executed function. Therefore it is not accessible from the outside. Only `Outer` can be accessed since you return it from that function.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072556/objects-dont-inherit-prototyped-functions/11072626#11072626) for a very good explanation of inheritance done right in JavaScript.

Comment: Cool. What about the `Inner` function? The `Extensions.Greet` function must also be able to be called on an `Inner` object.

Comment: You can do it exactly the same way. Define it inside the closure and return a new instance from the `getInner` method.

Comment: Could you add that to the code so I can see it? It's a little hard to see it in my mind's eye. Especially since I'm still trying to grok the fancy stuff like `call`.

Comment: Updated... `call` just sets `this` to the value you pass as first argument. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Yeah, I knew that, just hadn't seen it in action much. You gave me the idea of encapsulating everything into a function like you did, but without the extra closure stuff, just to hide the functions. Is that a bad idea? If so, why?

Comment: @Kendall: I don't understand what you mean... what should be a bad idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13019/discussion-between-kendall-frey-and-felix-kling)