# Accessing an object's property from a prototyped sub object

Tags: javascript, prototype

Given the following code is it posible to access an object's property from inside a "sub" object?

I imagine I'm doing this completely wrong, but I'm not sure what the right pattern to do is here. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function MainObject(){
    this.someProperty = "asdf";
    return this;
}

MainObject.prototype.subClass = {};
MainObject.prototype.subClass.sayHi = function(){
    // 'this' refers to the instance of MainObject.subClass
    // How do I get to the instance's MainObject.someProperty property from here,
    // without calling "widget.someProperty"?
};

widget = new MainObject();
```

Comment: *"I imagine I'm doing this completely wrong..."* Perhaps, what are you trying to achieve? Some kind of "inner class"-like thing? If you're trying to do inheritance (rather than "inner" stuff), [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11072626/157247) here on SO has a full example with explanation.

Comment: I want MainObject to comprise a single point from which a user can access my whole JS library. So after the line: `widget = new MainObject();` a user would only need to call `widget` to interact with my library. Internally my library would do many different things, but should never need to know that `widget` was the variable the user chose to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't since there is no reference to the actual instance. You'd have to initialize `subClass` for each instance inside the constructor:

```
function MainObject(){
    var self = this;
    this.someProperty = "asdf";
    this.subClass = {};
    this.subClass.sayHi = function(){
        //self.someProperty
    }
};
```

But that replicates functionality. It seems you should choose an other approach altogether.

Maybe using **composition** would be better, but that really depends on what you are trying to do and how the "classes" relate to each other.

```
function SubClass(instance) {
    this.instance = instance;
}

SubClass.prototype.sayHi = ...;

function MainObject(){
    this.someProperty = "asdf";
    this.subClass = new SubClass(this);
}
```

Comment: I used a poor choice calling it "subClass" when really its just going to be a separate class altogether, I just want it to be accessible from a single instance point. `widget` should be the only variable that a user needs to instantiate to use my library. I don't think this pattern would work in that case is that correct?

Comment: @ianneub: I that case I think you are looking for some module pattern. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647258/how-to-use-revealing-module-pattern-in-javascript

Comment: I went ahead and marked your answer as the solution. I ended up changing the way I handle the API and instead of allowing the user to instantiate the object for them, I do it in my code and present them with that object. More similar to how jQuery does it.

Thanks also to T.J. Crowder, those were very valuable links.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reference to the actual parent, so you'll have to store one manually in the subclass. Here's an example:

```
function MainObject() {
    // your code

    this.subClass = {
        parent: this
    }
}
```

Comment: @FelixKling: That is correct. You'd want to do this call inside the constructor for MainObject--I should clarify.

Comment: That won't work either, you will override `subClass` for each instance, i.e. `subClass.parent` will always refer to the last created instance.

Comment: this is the correct answer, although it can be simplified to just `this.subClass.parent = this;`

Comment: @Jason: No, because then you'd get `subClass is undefined.`

Comment: not if you prototype your subclass: `MyClass.prototype.subClass`

Comment: Simpler to do what I already have than create `subClass` on the object's prototype and then set the property manually later...