# Issue in inheritance in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using inheritance in javascript. I am stuck in a situation where i have to check whether  the First object inherited in the Second object. Example :

```
   function Parent(name)
   {
     var self = this;

     self.Name = name;

     self.Check = function() {
       for(var i = 0; i < ChildCollection.length ;i++)
       {
          //here i want to check whether self is the object which is
          //inherited in ChildCollection[i] 

          alert(true or false);
       }
     }
   }

   function Child(name)
   {
     var self = this;

     Child.prototype.constructor = Child;   

     self.Name = name;
   }

   $(function() {       

      var ChildCollection = new Array()

      for(var i = 1; i <= 2 ;i++)
      {
         Child.prototype = new Parent("TestParent_" + i);              
         var child = new Child("TestChild_" + i);
         ChildCollection.push(child);
      }             

       ChildCollection[1].Check();
    });
```

In the above code i have created 2 classes `Parent` and `Child`. Child inherit Parent. I have create a global `ChildCollection` Array which contains all child objects. In parent class there is a check function which i want to create, it should loop through the `ChildCollection` array and check whether the current object means (self or this) is inherited or a part of current looped child object.

To make very clear i called check on ChildCollection's second object i.e. `ChildCollection[1].Check()`. If i am clear or not wrong than first alert should be false and second alert should be true.

Please guid me to solve this issue and sorry if i am on totally on wrong track and please explain me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above code i have created 2 classes Parent and Child. Child inherit Parent.

The way you're doing that is very, very unusual. You're giving `Child` a new and different prototype just before every time you use it. That's probably not what you want to do. [This other answer here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11072626/157247) provides an example of the "usual" way of doing inheritance in JavaScript. I've also written a helper script called [`Lineage`](https://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/) to reduce the typing involved.

> I have create a global `ChildCollection` Array which contains all child objects.

It's not a global, it's a variable within your `ready` callback (the function you're passing into `$()`). It's not accessible from `Parent` where you've defined `Parent`, and so this line:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ChildCollection.length ;i++)
```

...will fail with a `ReferenceError`.

You can fix that in one of three ways:

1. Passing `ChildCollection` into the `Parent` contructor as an argument.
2. Making `ChildCollection` actually global (which I would avoid).
3. Moving your `Parent` and `Child` functions *into* your `ready` callback so they have access to it.

And actually, to avoid creating globals (`Parent` and `Child`) but avoid having `Parent` rely on a pseudo-global, you can combine #1 and #3.

Re the code comment:

> here i want to check whether self is the object which is
>   inherited in ChildCollection[i]

I don't know what you mean by "inherited" in that sentence, but if you want to know whether `self` is in `ChildCollection`:

```
var found = false;
for(var i = 0; !found && i < ChildCollection.length; i++) {
    if (ChildCollection[i] === self) {
        found = true;
    }
}
alert(found);
```