# Trying to understand inheritance in JavaScript -- what's going on here?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

Why does this say "Animal" instead of "kitty"?

```
// create base class Animal
function Animal(animalType) {
    this.type = animalType;
    this.sayType = function () {
        alert(this.type);
    };
}

// create derived class Cat
function Cat(myName) {
    Animal.call(this, "cat"); // cat calls the Animal base class constructor

    this.name = myName;

    this.sayName = function () {
        alert(this.name);
    };
}

Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal); // set Cat's prototype to Animal

// instantiate a new instance of Cat
var cat = new Cat("kitty");

cat.sayName();
cat.name = "lol";
cat.sayName();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dgcoffman/MguUA/5/

Comment: your `sayType` and `sayName` functions aren't actually using prototypical inheritance _because they're not on the prototype_!  You've created them as instance-local properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Object.create(Animal); // set Cat's prototype to Animal
> ```

Yes, but to the `Animal` constructor function (or, to be exact: to a new object inheriting from that function object - check the [docs for `Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)). That's hardly what you want - and explains your curious result of saying `"Animal"`, as that's the `Animal` [function's `name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

Instead, you want to build a prototype chain, so that cat instances inherit from `Cat.prototype` which inherits from *`Animal.prototype`* (which inherits from `Object.prototype`):

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
```

Also, for prototypical inheritance, you should but the `sayName` and `sayType` methods on the prototype object (and only once):

```
Animal.prototype.sayType = function() {
    alert(this.type);
};
Cat.prototype.sayName = function() { // after creation of that object, of course
    alert(this.name);
};
```

Comment: OK I admit that maybe that's what he wants to do; since the Animal prototype isn't mentioned at all, this didn't occur to me. It is however a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I do this, I get Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Animal> has no method 'sayName'

http://jsfiddle.net/dgcoffman/MguUA/7/

Nevermind, I was overwriting Cat's prototype after I added the sayName function to it, fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/dgcoffman/MguUA/8/

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `Object.create()` in a way that does something different than what I bet you think it does. Try this change:

```
Cat.prototype = Object.create(new Animal);
```

The `Object.create()` function expects its first argument to be the **object** to be used as the prototype for the returned object.  When you pass in the function name "Animal", that means you want the prototype object to be that function object, and not an object *constructed* by the function.

*edit* — Bergi's answer involving the direct use of the Animal prototype probably makes more sense, though from what you posted there isn't an Animal prototype object with anything interesting on it. Perhaps that's elsewhere in your code, or will be added later.  Anyway if it does exist it's better to do as in his answer.

Since your "Cat" constructor is picking up the "sayType" property from the Animal constructor directly, it's not clear what you're trying to do by setting the Cat prototype.

Comment: @Bergi huh?  You're making me frantic here :-)  That makes the fiddle work like I'd think it should work, but I admit that I'm not sure why overriding "name" with "kitty" doesn't work.  It's also confusing because setting the prototype is silly given the `.call()` in the "Cat" constructor.

Comment: I know JS better than 99% of people here but prototypical inheritance still confuses the hell out of me :(

Comment: @Alnitak lol I know; I find that I hardly ever use inheritance beyond a few simple types here and there.

Comment: That doubles up the prototype chain :-) http://stackoverflow.com/q/12592913/1048572 (and sorry about mistaking you for @PointedEars :-)

Comment: Yup, always inherit from the prototype, not from an instance.

Comment: Ah OK yes well that makes sense.  There's a really good T. J. Crowder answer floating around out there that's got all sorts of interesting stuff about how/why to set up prototype chains.

Comment: this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11072556/objects-dont-inherit-prototyped-functions/11072626#11072626